# Virtualenv have multiple possible locations

Tags: django, bash, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

A colleague of mine implement a shell script with the following line

```
output="$(venv/bin/python manage.py has_missing_migrations --quiet --settings=project.tests_settings 2>&1)"
```

Here is the full code :

```
# Check missing migrations

  output="$(venv/bin/python manage.py has_missing_migrations --quiet --settings=project.tests_settings 2>&1)"
  [ $? -ne 0 ] \
      && ipoopoomypants "Migrations" "$output" \
      || irock "Migrations"
```

If I run the script, I obtain

```
Running pre-commit checks:
  [OK] anonymize_db ORM queries
  [OK] Forbidden Python keywords
  [OK] Forbidden JavaScript keywords
  [OK] Forbidden HTML keywords
[FAIL] Migrations

COMMIT REJECTED: .git/hooks/pre-commit: line 88: venv/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

The problem with the above line is it takes into account that the virtual environment has been created inside the project itself. However, it is not always the case. From what I am concerned, I work with virtualenvwrapper. Hence, my virtualenv is not `./venv`, but well in `~/.virtualenvs/venv`.

Question : How could I modify the above line in such a way it will consider both path `./venv` and `~/.virtualenvs/venv`?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the `WORKON_HOME` environment variable to point the the location of virtualenvs instead of hard-coding it.